# script to convert all .txt file content to lowercase

Tags: windows, powershell, lowercase

I have about 700 .txt files scattered in 300 directories and sub-directories.

I would like to open each of them, convert all text inside to lowercase, including Unicode characters (such as `É` to `é`), then save and close them.

Can you advise how it could be done through PowerShell? It is my own computer and I have admin rights.

I have started with the below:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\tmp -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {}
```

but I am not sure what to put between the brackets of `ForEach-Object {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple script, with your requirements:

```
$path=".\test\*.txt"
#With Default system encoding
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | foreach{    
    (Get-Content $_.FullName).ToLower() | Out-File $_.FullName
}

#Or with specified encoding    
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | foreach{    
(Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Unicode).ToLower() | 
    Out-File $_.FullName -Encoding Unicode
}
#Test
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | foreach{
    Write-Host "`n File ($_.FullName): `n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    Get-Content $_.FullName    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use :

```
# Reading the file content and converting it to lowercase and finally putting the content back to the file with the same filename.
(Get-Content C:\path\file.txt -Raw).ToLower() | Out-File C:\path\file.txt -Force
```

inside the foreach and then change the case to lower.

If you want to iterate all the files in the corresponding folder then you can use another foreach to get that job done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this:
Get-ChildItem C:\tmp -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_ -Raw).ToLower() | Out-File $_ -Force}
but it returns errors :(

Comment: This one works:
Get-ChildItem D:\test -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content D:test\$_ -Raw).ToLower() | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force}
but how can I limit it to .txt files only?

Comment: pretty straight forward.try this :`Get-ChildItem D:\test -Recurse -File -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content D:test\$_ -Raw).ToLower()} | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force` 
Use -Include *.txt for specifying the txt files only.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable

Comment: Sure, I'd love to accept the answer, but I am getting the error message below :(
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\test\'.
At line:1 char:113
+ ... {(Get-Content D:test\$_ -Raw).ToLower()} | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: am trying this:
Get-ChildItem D:\test -Recurse -File -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content D:\test\$_ -Raw).ToLower()} | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force
error:
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\test\'.
At line:1 char:114
+ ... (Get-Content D:\test\$_ -Raw).ToLower()} | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: $_ indicates the current pipeline object . So it is expecting a filename which is not getting. `| Out-File D:\test\Filename.txt`  will work.

Comment: It still does not work. Can you try the full command on your end?

Comment: It is clearly telling that the directory is not present in the out-file part. Do you have the `D:\Test` folder. If not change it according to your need.

Comment: show me the full command what you are using and share me the drive structure.

Comment: Get-ChildItem D:\test -Recurse -File -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content D:\test\$_ -Raw).ToLower()} | Out-File D:\test\$_ -Force

and the drive structure is simply D:\test with plenty of sub-directories in there

Comment: Yes, but my paths are specific. I am not using $_ as a file path. rather i am using foreach to get each file, then get the content. then finally write it back with the same name. once done with one file go back to the folder content

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: Change the logic a little bit. First iterate all the files in a foreach which are with .txt , then put another foreach loop to make the content lower case and set it back with the same file name. Once that is  done you are good to go

Comment: I still don't get it, it returns the same errors :(